# slick slider dots repositioning - multiple positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). I was wondering if it is possible to reposition slick dots for a particular slick slider only (by "slider" I mean the full slider, not an image in the slider. I have 3 slick slides on my page, just want to move it for one of them).

I found this post [slick slider dots repositioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219819/slick-slider-dots) re-positioning and the accepted solution works fine as long as you want to move all your dots (for all sliders together):

```css
.slick-dots {
  top: 100px;  // play with the number of pixels to position it as you want
  left: 100px; // play with the number of pixels to position it as you want
}
```

How can reposition the dots only for a particular slider? The .slick-dots class seems to apply to all sliders and the source code is in the CDN.

For code reference please refer to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/89/ (note this is just an example of 1 slider, not a full representation of the issue at hand).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use a more recent version of the plugin, the current version is 1.8.1

Then you can use the `afterChange` event to set a distinct attribute on the element which you can use to target it with CSS for styling.

For example,

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange',function(e, slick, currentSlide){
    slick.$dots.attr('data-current-slide', currentSlide);
});
```

The above will set an attribute named `data-current-slide` with a value that matches the current slide. Now you can target it with CSS with the `[data-current-slide="XX"]` for styling purposes.

For example using

```
.slick-dots[data-current-slide="3"]{
    bottom: -20px;
}
```

will move the dots below the photos when you are on slide 3.
*note: the current slide depends on how you use the `slidesToScroll` option*

See demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/1hoztaay/

Comment: Thanks Gaby. However this is not what I meant. I do not intend to move the dots for a particular image in a slick slide as to which your solution refers. I want to move the dots for a particular slick slider (all images in the slick slider). As explained in my question, I have 3 slick sliders on my page, and just 1 should have the dots on top. The fiddle I provided is an example code of 1 slick slider. Would appreciate if you can adjust your answer if you know the solution.

Comment: @tealowpillow that is even easier. Just add an id to the slider you want to differentiate and use that to create a CSS rule to change the style. Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/529cnmmo/